# Using Spring's JDBC support to get output parameters

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, output-parameter

I'm using Spring's JDBC support to run SQL queries and updates on an Oracle database.  I'd like to insert a row and then get the key that it was assigned (using an Oracle sequence).  In normal JDBC code, I would include a RETURNING INTO clause and then register an output parameter ([well described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682539/return-rowid-parameter-from-insert-statement-using-jdbc-connection-to-oracle))

However, I would like to just use Spring to handle all my JDBC work for me.  For non-insert SQL statements, I'm currently using a MapSqlParameterSource object and registering all my input parameters.  Can I also register an output parameter like this and have it returned to me?  I looked over the Chapter 11 portion of the Spring docs, and I saw there was support for an output parameter if I'm using stored procedures, but I would like to avoid doing that if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Spring JDBC support API provides explicit support for OUT parameters, so you may need to step back a bit and use the more general query API provided by `JdbcTemplate`:

```
Object execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementCallback action)
```

This lets you perform arbitrary JDBC operations within the scope of a Spring-managed connection and `PrepatedStatement`. The downside is that the handling and tidyup of things like `ResultSets` becomes your problem.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I'll have to look at the PreparedStatementCreator though.  My main reason for using Spring was to grab the connection info from the framework and to keep my JDBC code tidy.  It looks like I'm back to the try/catch/finally code.

Comment: Spring will still do the connection and statement housekeeping for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code - it may do what you want, not sure if Oracle supports this syntax though.

[getReturnedGeneratedKeys() Spring JDBC Excample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/Returngeneratedkeys.htm)